# WIN32 : PictureBox Does Not Display Picture

Tags: c, winapi

I am using WIN32 and C programming to do a window dialog in Visual Studio 2008 in the Windows CE OS using Windows 5.0 Mobile SDK. I insert my two picture boxes using the Resource Dialog Editor and ensure they are allocated IDs in the window resource. I am using SHLoadDIBitmap to display the image. My code compiles without errors but when I run the program, no images appear in the two picture boxes. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include "ScanCAPI.h"
#include "resource.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "Kernel32.lib")

HBITMAP hImage;
HBITMAP hImage1;

.
.
.

    switch(uMsg)
    {

        case WM_INITDIALOG:

            hImage = SHLoadDIBitmap(TEXT("\\My Documents\\image1.bmp"));
            hImage1 = SHLoadDIBitmap(TEXT("\\My Documents\\image2.bmp"));
            if (hImage==NULL) {
               MessageBox(0,"hImage returned null",0,0);
            } else {
            hnd_pic1 = GetDlgItem(hwnd,IDC_STATIC8);
            SendMessage(hnd_pic1, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hImage);
            }


            hnd_pic2 = GetDlgItem(hwnd,IDC_STATIC9);
             if (hImage1==NULL) {
              MessageBox(0,"hImage1 returned null",0,0);
            } else {
            SendMessage(hnd_pic2, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hImage1);
}
```

Comment: There's no error handling code at all. Don't have us guess, when the answers to vital questions are right in front of you.

Comment: Does `SHLoadDIBitmap` return a valid handle?  That's a rather deprecated Win32 function if I might add.

Comment: Are those `imageX.bmp` files in the *current working directory*. otherwise, you might need to specify the full path if the function is returning NULL.

Comment: Yes @selbie, I made sure the bitmaps are in the same directory as the app.

Comment: Right, but Visual Studio will launch the program from the project directory as current working.  Or if you launch it yourself, it will be the EXEs folder.  Either way, your current working may not be what you think it is.

Comment: The application directory is not necessarily the current working directory. I mean, there's [SetCurrentDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcurrentdirectory), so you already know that that hypothetical invariant doesn't hold. Anyway, stop guessing, and start by observing error conditions.

Comment: @Ezani - you really need to provide an [mcve]. I'm happy to help, but I can't solve your issue given what you've provided.  Now please answer my original question, does SHLoadDIBitmap succeed?

Comment: @IInspectable, I checked in File Explorer that the bitmaps are in the same directory as the app EXE. That's why I didn't set any path information before the filename but used the filename directly. And then I placed the bitmaps in the SAME directory as the app EXE.

Comment: Thanks selbie, IInspectable for your advise on error checking. I added error checking to SHLoadDIBitmap (see updated code above) and no it is not succeeding, It is returning NULL. But image1.bmp and image2.bmp DOES exist in the same folder as the EXE. I just copied and pasted it there.

Comment: You're confusing a static concept (filesystem layout) with a runtime concept (the current working directory). You cannot use the former to statically verify the outcome of the latter at runtime. I cannot think of a single reason to ever use a relative path. Use a fully qualified pathname instead.

Comment: Ok, I've modifed my path as fully qualified pathnames but still no image in picture boxes.

Comment: Those aren't [fully qualified pathnames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#fully-qualified-vs-relative-paths).

Comment: @IInspectable, there are no fully qualified pathnames in WinCE. Only relative paths. The file structure in WinCE has been compacted and flattened as compared to a full Windows OS. So you won't have "C:\1.txt" but rather "\My Documents\1.txt".

Comment: The syntax may be different, but WinCE most certainly has the notion of fully qualified pathnames. And you aren't using fully qualified pathnames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code sample works for me on Windows 10 (`SHLoadDIBitmap` API seems not valid for Windows 10. I use `LoadImage` API instead.). You can refer to.

C++ code in dialog box procedure:

```
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    hImage = LoadImage(NULL, L"full_path_to\\image3.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_DEFAULTSIZE);
    if (NULL == hImage)
        errCode = GetLastError();

    hwd_static_img = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATIC6);
    SendMessage(hwd_static_img, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hImage);
    return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
```

Resource script in project_name.rc file:

```
CONTROL         "",IDC_STATIC6,"Static", SS_BITMAP,37,133,136,109
```

Two notes:

1. **Make sure the image file is a valid bitmap file**. For example, you can draw a picture and save as a bitmap using mspaint.exe. If you rename a file from `.PNG` to `.BMP`, `LoadImage` will return a `NULL` handle but `GetLastError` return `0` which indicate no error.
2. Make sure set **`SS_BITMAP` static control style** for picture control (`IDC_STATIC6`).

BTW, no need to put image file in same directory with your project or EXE. Specify the valid full path of the image file will work.